# Change ui-widget-overlay width of modal popup

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, modalpopups

I am using jQuery 'UI 1.8.11' for modal popup and I want to change the width of the modal popup appearing on the screen.

I want to change the inline style of div with class "ui-widget-overlay" which gets generated when the modal opens up .The height and width are set to the windows height and width.

I am unable to figure out where to set the height and width in the 'jQuery UI 1.8.11' .